# Lucene indexwriter.close() is a must?

Tags: lucene

My program was running too slow that I had to terminate it halfway to optimize some part of the codes right after 40,000 documents was inserted into database, BUT, before Lucene indexwriter.close was called. Then I couldn't find any results for some of the records that seems to be limited to the 40,000 documents from that particular run.

Does that mean that those record which I had index during the program run was lost? IndexWriter must always be perfectly closed to allow for the data to be written to the index?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not close that you need to call but [commit](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#commit%28%29). [addDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addDocument%28java.lang.Iterable%29) only analyzes the document and buffers data into memory while commit will flush pending changes and perform a fsync.

[close](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#close%28%29) calls commit internally, I think this is why you assume close is required.

However, beware of not calling commit too often as this operation is very costly compared to addDocument.